# TimeDelay in EJB2

Tags: java, ejb

One of the EJB class is calling an external API & I would like retry if there is a failure after some time delay. As managing thread is not a good idea (Thread.sleep(1000)) is not recommended, can someone tell me how to delay/suspend the process for a certain period of time in EJB2?.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your issue with sleeping for 1 second multiple times is the unnecessary waiting time if the thread is successful.

Instead of sleep, you could try using join instead.

```
join(5000)
```

would wait up to 5 seconds for the thread to finish. If it finishes early, your execution resumes. If it doesn't finish early, your execution resumes after 5 seconds.

The sleep method uses a [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29) technique whereas join uses a modified [interrupt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) scheme.

Comment: Thanks John.  In EJB container Managed & hibernate, is it safe to use Thread?.  The application will have 15 MDB & each MDB calls this EJB service which will have a small time delay ONLY if there is an Exception from the External API.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, if there is failure, then you can create a timer with appropriate time-out duration, which in this case will be delay duration.

In time-out method, you can again call EJB which will further call external API.